# How to neutralise / eliminate Lydia Boyle without attracting any guards / party guests nearby

Tags: dishonored

So... when you do the "Lady Boyle's Last Party" Mission, and you do not have shadow kill, and your given target is Lydia Boyle (the one in red), you will be led to music room. There, she will ask you to play a song on the piano. However, as the music room is open to guests and servants, once you kill her / knock her out, you will attract unwanted attention... how do you eliminate / neutralise her without attracting unwanted attention? (Let's say I have shadow kill tier 1. Even then, she won't turn to ash because she already noticed you. Am I right?)

Comment: I dont know about any piano but when i played the game i confronted her (in public) and after a conversation you can get her to follow you to the cellar. Obviously there are no guards or guests there so you can do your thing there.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma That would be Waverly Boyle, not Lydia Boyle. Waverly leads you to cellars, and Lydia leads to you music room (which is public). (Esma, if you want to know, leads you to upstairs bedroom)

Comment: i really remember this part of quest VERY different. as i read in posts and comments, Lydia Boyle is wearing red, check. but leading me to the music room? don't remember. ive done this quest by getting Lydia non-lethally but the only difference is that Lydia led me to the bedroom. im quite sure ive succeeded so what the hell happened in me? i also remember Lydia saying "Get to me now"(if you still don't get what she wants,i have bad news for you) or else she'll call the guards.

Comment: I believe the one that leads you to the bedroom is Esma Boyle not Lydia Boyle...

Comment: @KimMinseo is i've read in this question, yes it is esma. oddly, iv'e completed this particular mission(a non-lethal one at that). did my game bugged?

Comment: @ken There are 3 different targets that can be offered to you - Esma, Lydia and Waverly Boyle. By now, I have played the game twice, once with low chaos and once with high chaos. For my first time, my target was Esma - she led me to the bedroom. For my second time, I got Waverly as my target - she led me to the cellar. However, this time, I got Lydia as my target, and any other option that you take will cause her to call to the guards. So you have to choose the right option, and the right option will bring you to the open music room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the opportune moment... a long time...

She actually goes to the toilet sometimes. Kill her there and leave. If you want to keep her alive, it's a bit harder...

Firstly, you will need to reduce the number of unnamed guests in the room to the right to the opening hall. Knock them out and dump them in the room with the Wall of Light controls.

There is one guy there you can talk to. Go bother him until he gets the guard from across the room. Lure this guard into a quiet corner and remove him as a problem. Now you can get rid of the Overseer that was previously watched by said guard.

Proceed to remove as many guests as needed from this area (you can poison-dart everyone there quickly), grab the body and move upstairs quickly. From here, proceed to the stairwell at the other side of the mansion, down through the kitchen and deliver her.

Comment: So... I can still get the "Well Mannered" Achievenment after doing this?

Comment: @KimMinseo I believe that as long as you don't get seen you should be fine. About 75% sure :)

Comment: Thx! I'll try it!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to [this site](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Boyle's_Last_Party#Elimination), you can read all about the whole mission, including how to take Lady Boyle non-lethally.

I quote:
"*If Corvo talks to Lord Brisby, the partygoer wearing the rat mask in the smoking room, he will reveal his undying love for Lady Boyle. He will say that if Corvo can deliver Lady Boyle to him, Brisby will make sure that she is never seen again. As such, the mission can be completed by rendering Lady Boyle unconscious and delivering her to Lord Brisby in the cellar.*"

After you've talked to Brisby, and you've identified Lady Boyle (she can be any of the three), you can talk to her and get some dialogues. If you choose the right dialogues, she'll start walking down to the cellar with you. And when you've gone down the stairs and past the kitchen, you can take her out without anyone seeing it.

Comment: Same as the comment in the original post, I would like to say that this is only the case for Waverly Boyle, I am specially referring to Lydia Boyle, who instead of going to the cellar, goes to the music room.

Comment: If you only interact with Brisby, he will give you the Lady Boyle that will walk down to the cellar with you.
Edit:
If you really want to take Lydia Boyle stealthy, she can be killed with `Shadow Kill`, but if you want take care of her non-lethally, she will eventually go down to the cellar by her own to get some more brandy.

Answer (score 1):

One option is if you have the Bend Time II. Trigger Bend Time, knock Lydia out, then teleport away. You only have about 8 seconds of safe time, but I found it easy to pull off in the main hall (the one with the Light Wall). It might be helpful to Bend Time a second time to give you plenty of time to escape.

Another option is if you have Possession II. Possess Lydia and move her into a room, close the door, then remove the possession. While she is disoriented for a second, take her out.

Note that Lydia will path fairly close to the room leading to the cellar, you should be able to get directly to the boat without much trouble using either of these methods.

Another good place is the room with the Light Wall. You can either Bend Time and teleport up with Blink II, or Possession will last long enough to move her into a room upstairs.

Please note that with either of these methods, it may be necessary to take out any nearby Overseers. Their music boxes will render your magic useless if they catch you and stop playing.

Comment: This would work also, but normally, at that stage, you normally don't have enough runes to get bend time tier 2 or possession tier 2...

Comment: At this stage I had Blink 2, Bend Time 2, Possession 1, Agility 2. I actually just completed a full ghost no-kill run yesterday :)

Comment: I always get windblast 2 early, so most of the runes are used up...

Answer (score 1):

If you speak with Lydia, you have the option of luring her to the basement instead of the music room. There is no one around there.